# Mark an empty space into an array without using null

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I am extending `AbstractMap` and I want to implement my own hash-map using two parallel arrays:

```
K[] keys;
V[] values;
```

Suppose I want to store `null` values as well, how could I initialize these two arrays so that I can differentiate between a space in the array where I could place some new key-value pairs and a space where I am storing a `null`?

Comment: Why would you be storing a `null`?  Are you going to allow `null` as a valid key?

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest not using two arrays, and instead do something along the lines of:

```
class Node {
    K key;
    V value;
}

Node[] nodes;
```

Then a non-entry is an element in `nodes` that is equal to `null`.

Comment: your solution seems efficient, but I was wondering how the same solution could be achieved using only arrays. I have heard many times of marking empty spaces without using null, but I never understood how...and as @OliCharlesworth was saying it is not possibile to cast K to Object..

Answer (score 0):

If the values can be null but the keys cannot be null then having a null key would mean that there is no key.

If the key can also be null you can use a parallel array of booleans to store whether each space is taken or not.

```
K[] keys;
V[] values;
boolean[] hasValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure the details of your question, but you could always have some special object for your "blank".

```
private static final Object BLANK = new Object();
```

Then if the item in the array `== BLANK`, then consider it to be an empty slot.

Comment: it should be `.equals(BLANK)` unless there's something special about the object.

Comment: It's static, so it's always the same object as in the variable references the same object.

Comment: Won't there be a typing issue here?  You can't store an `Object` in a `K[]`.

Comment: That's true, but he could just use a static K BLANK.

Comment: @Jon, I would recommend using `==` for this static final placeholder. It is more efficient and more clear what is going on that way. Using `.equals` has possible potential for problems.

Comment: @Oli, Good point. The OP may need to make the array non-specific to `K`, and using casting where necessary. Since `K` is generic (isn't it?), he will not have a dependable way to create a single `static final K BLANK`. Therefore he must replace `K[]` with `Object[]`, or use another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since there can only be one null key, you can simply have a special reference value (not in the array) that holds the value of the object mapped from this null key (and possibly a boolean indicating if this value has been set).  Unfortunately this will probably complicate iteration.

E.g.

```
private boolean isNullMapped = false;
private V nullValue = null;

public put(K key, V value)
{
  if (key == null) { nullValue = value; }
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can wrap all keys in a wrapper object (supposing you still want to use parallel arrays instead of entries), and if the value contained in this wrapper object is null, then it represents the null key.

E.g.

```
private static class KeyWrapper<K>
{
  public K key;
}
```

Lastly, as a question for consideration, if you are not having entries in your arrays, but instead are directly holding arrays of K and V, then how are you accounting for different keys that happen to share the same hash code?  The java.util implementation has arrays of entries that also act as linked lists to account for this possibility (and incidentally, the null key is always mapped to array index 0).

Answer (score 0):

Storing a `null` **value** is not a problem in your scenario. So long as `keys[n] != null`, just return `values[n]` whether `values[n]` is `null` or not.

Remember that you are not being asked to key on `n` but objects of type `K` so every access of the `Map` will require a search through `keys` to find the key they are looking for.

However, if you want to allow the storage of a `value` against a `null` key then using something like `private static final Object NULL_KEY = "NULL"` would probably do the trick as the other suggestions point out.

```
private static final Object NULL_KEY = "NULL";
K[] keys;
V[] values;

private int find(K key) {
  for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i] == key) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
  V old = null;
  if (key != null) {
    int i = find(key);
    if (i >= 0) {
      old = values[i];
      values[i] = value;
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  } else {
    return put((K) NULL_KEY, value);
  }
  return old;
}

public V get(K key) {
  if (key != null) {
    int i = find(key);
    if (i >= 0) {
      return values[i];
    }
    return null;
  } else {
    return (get((K) NULL_KEY));
  }
}
```

Comment: As commentators on other suggestions pointed out, your NULL_KEY Object cannot be cast to K.

Comment: @increment1 - Notice that at no time do I return NULL_KEY. It is only used in the `keys[]` to indicate that `null` was used as the key. The return value will always be of type `V`. User will never be aware of its use, that is why it is a `private static final` object.

Comment: @increment1 - You are right, forgive me I missed your point ... however, casting `Object` to type `K` should merely be a matter of suppressing warnings at the relevant places. Perhaps I could "leave that as an exercise for the student" <grin>.

Answer (score -1):

In the java.util implementation a special object representing null is used.